# The way to callback a function

Tags: javascript, callback

Here I'm trying to make both divs red, via the callback. However, it works only for one, not for both.

I know, it's probably not very clever question, but I really spend several hours trying to understand why it doesn't work.

What's wrong with it?

```
<div id="foo">foo</div>
<div id="bar">bar</div>

<script>

function foo() {
    document.querySelector("#foo").style.color = "red";
}

function bar() {
    document.querySelector("#bar").style.color = "red";
}

foo(bar);

</script>
```

Comment: How exactly did you expect it to work? `bar` is never called and `foo` ignores passed arguments.

Comment: @james, just change `foo(bar);` to `foo(); bar();`. Please don't use the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `foo(bar)`, it passes the function `bar` as an argument to `foo`.  Yet `foo` doesn't list any arguments and you're not calling `bar` in it either.  Change your `foo` function like so.

```
function foo(callback) {
    document.querySelector("#foo").style.color = "red";
    callback();
}
```

---

**Update**

This solution is not the best practice however for your situation.  What you're trying to accomplish doesn't require a callback.  You should do one of the following.

- Combine these two functions into one.
- Call `foo` and `bar` together.

You should avoid using a callback in such a simple case as this.

Comment: please, please don't do this. please just call both functions: `foo(); bar();` or put the code of both functions into one: `function foo() {
    document.querySelector("#foo").style.color = "red";
    document.querySelector("#bar").style.color = "red";
}` and just call `foo();`

Comment: Although I agree with your answer that this is pretty silly, I still wanted to give an answer that shows how to do callbacks.  But I will say that for this specific example, you don't need the callback.  He really should be calling both functions or combining them.

Comment: Yes, I've got that, but the way he asks shows, that he doesn't have the experience to necessarily understand your intentions. I'm just worried that he might think that this would be the right way to go/to write such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions but are only calling one:

```
foo(bar);
```

only passes the `bar` function to `foo`, which doesn't do anything with it.

to get this working call both functions:

```
foo();
bar();
```